# How do I use this variable in if statement in a loop (scope)

Tags: c, scope, arduino

I'm programming something with an Arduino, which I believe uses C as the base language.  I have this loop:

```
int i = 0;

void loop()
{
    //Set The output pin to the MIDI note number - 60.
    int pinNumber = noteNumber - 60;

    if (midiMessage == 144) {
        if (velocity == Triggered) {
            registerWrite(pinNumber, HIGH);
            i = pinNumber;
        }
    }

    if (midiMessage == 128) {
        if ((i % 8) == (pinNumber % 8)) {
            if (velocity == Stopped) {
                registerWrite(pinNumber, LOW);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know the above code doesn't work right, but what I'm trying to do is assign the `i` variable if the first condition is met `if (velocity == Triggered)`, and then be able to use it when the `midiMessage == 128` condition is met.

Comment: I didn't see anything wrong here, what's you output message for this error?

Comment: Well with an arduino, it's hard to get an output message. :)  But, are you saying that if `i = 2` inside the first condition, that the next time the loop runs `if (midiMessage==128)` then `i = 2` or `i = 0`?

Comment: i == 2, if you didn't change i between the two loops.

Comment: No, Arduino uses (a subset of) C++ as the base language. "[Wiring and Processing have spawned another project, Arduino, which uses the Processing IDE together with a simplified version of the C++ programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiring_%28development_platform%29#Arduino_and_Fritzing)". See [Writing a Library for Arduino](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/LibraryTutorial) for an example using classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is a global variable, meaning that it's initialised to 0 (explicitly) when your program starts, and then can be changed by any code that can see it.

So, if your question is:

> Will it maintain its value between different calls to the `loop()` function?"

(and it seems to be, based on the comments you left in the question) then the answer is yes.

In other words, when you enter `loop()` with `midiMessage` equal to 144, it will set `i` to `pinNumber` (`noteNumber - 60`).

Then the next time you enter `loop()` with `midiMessage` equal to 128, it will use the current `i` (whatever it was last set to).

Of course, if you enter `loop()` with `midiMessage` equal to 128 *before* you call it when `midiMessage` equals 144, the value of `i` will be zero.

---

If that declaration of `i` was *inside* the `loop()` function, then it would be re-initialised each time the function was called, but that's not the case here.

Of course, good programming practice would suggest that you should put it inside the function *if that's the only place you use it* (this may not be the case).

This restricts its "visibility" <sup>(a)</sup> to that function so that there's no chance other code may use it inadvertently (this is *especially* a problem for a variable called `i` - you may want to think of a better name for it).

To restrict its visibility like that while still allowing it to exist between function calls, you would use something like:

```
void loop (void) {
    static int persistentVar = 0;
    :
    :
}
```

This still initialises it once, at program startup (even though it's inside the function) and keeps its value in between different invocations of `loop()`. It also stops code from outside of that function from "seeing" the variable.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Note that "visibility" as used here is not the term the ISO standard uses. I use that term for my introductory coding classes since "visibility" is easier understood than "scope".

Comment: Thank you so much for the thorough explanation!